# Is it possible to configure mailman such that it doesn't communicate with the MTA using files?

Tags: exim, mailman

I am experimenting with containerizing Mailman 3. Currently, it seems like it's supposed to write to a directory which the MTA can read. Essentially the directory `/var/lists/` is used such that a subdirectory in the form of `<list>.<domain>` tells the MTA to receive list mail. You can see this here in the [exim conf they use an example](https://docs.mailman3.org/projects/mailman/en/latest/src/mailman/docs/mta.html#exim),

```
MM3_LMTP_PORT=8024

# MM3_HOME must be set to mailman's var directory, wherever it is
# according to your installation.
MM3_HOME=/opt/mailman/var
MM3_UID=list
MM3_GID=list

################################################################
# The configuration below is boilerplate:
# you should not need to change it.

# The path to the list receipt (used as the required file when
# matching list addresses)
MM3_LISTCHK=MM3_HOME/lists/${local_part}.${domain}
```

A directory like this,

```
/var/lists/foo.bar.com
```

Tells Exim to accept mail at `foo@bar.com` as deliverable.

Is it possible to configure Mailman3 and Exim such that files aren't used? This is desirable because I would like Mailman3 to run in a rootless container (separate filesystem namespace) so a compromised Mailman can't access other files owned by the Exim user (and vise-versa, that a compromised Exim can't get raw-write access to the mailing list store).